# Qt Creator qmake intergrate a HTML preprocessor

Tags: html, qmake

I am using the c preprocessor for simple #include substitution as per [link](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/cpre.html). Below is a snippet from my preprocessor.pri

```
HEADERS += $$PWD/include/header.htm


PREPROCESS_FILES = $$PWD/staff/courses.htm
preprocess.name = preprocess-htm-includes
preprocess.CONFIG += no_link no_clean

for(htm, PREPROCESS_FILES):preprocess.commands = cpp  -E -x c -P $${htm} > $${htm}l

first.depends = $(first) preprocess 
export(first.depends)
```

Firstly I am using a for loop as ${QMAKE_FILE_NAME} is always blank ? 
As I can't use ${QMAKE_FILE_BASE} I am unsure how to direct the pre-processor output to $$shadowed($$PWD)/.

Secondly As CPP (C Pre Processor) handling of comments and special characters isn't ideal for HTML (notably homeless ' and " also the -C    for ignoring comments prefixs a long GNU comment to the output html) are there any General Pre Processors that integrate well with Qt Creator I would like to keep all my debugging inside the IDE.

(bonus points if it did html/css/js minification and or validation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else trying to do the same it is easiest if you place a custom-compiler.pri (example below) in each folder containing source.htm that way all build hierarchy is maintained. NB* the name and SOURCES varaible of the custom compiler must be unique !

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD

HEADERS += $$top_srcdir/docroot/include/*.htm

SOURCES_HTM_STAFF += $$PWD/*.htm
htm_staff.name = htm
htm_staff.input = SOURCES_HTM_STAFF
htm_staff.dependency_type = TYPE_C
htm_staff.variable_out = JUNK
htm_staff.output = $$shadowed($$PWD)/${QMAKE_FILE_IN_BASE}.html
htm_staff.CONFIG = no_link target_predeps
htm_staff.commands = cpp  -E -x c -P ${QMAKE_FILE_NAME} > ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT}
QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += htm_staff
```

The result a c like environment for preprocessing html source files containing #includes "header.htm"

Issues:

- cpp will ignore C comments which might contain data that should be displayed. The -C flag fixes this but cpp then slaps on a gpl notice to ever file to which I am unsure how to suppress ?
- unterminated character constant like ' or " will throw a critical error For example, if the source document contains the word Don't